# When drawing the sea temperature gradient map with the data of Himawari-8, why the image is mirrored?

Tags: matlab, sst

When the data of Sunflower No. 8 is used, the image obtained is mirrored：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxJ0l.jpg)

And the result should be like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2GCd.png)

In addition, the area on the map does not correspond to the entered longitude and latitude, below is the code to get the latitude and longitude area I need

```
clc
clear all
load('20210130_daily_sst.mat');%,[1,1,1],[inf,inf,1]));
load('grid.mat', 'lon')
load('grid.mat', 'lat')
lon=lon(1,:);lat=lat(:,1);

lon1=find(lon==118);
lon2=find(lon==130);
lat1=find(lat==24);
lat2=find(lat==42);


lx=lon(lon1:lon2);
ly=lat(lat1:lat2);
[x,y]=meshgrid(lx,ly);
x=x'; y=y';
sst0= SST(lon1:lon2,lat2:lat1);
```

But these problems will not occur when using MODIS data.

Comment: I assume SST in this case its not " SST (selenium-simple-test) is a web test framework that uses Python to generate functional browser-based tests. " like the tag you are using. Care to explain what that is?

Comment: in any case, functions like `flip` will flip your data. you can use that

Comment: Thanks for your answer! SST is sea surface temperature